# Error in dim(data) <- dim : invalid first argument

Tags: r, syntax-error

I am trying to run this code but I keep receiving an error message saying

> Error in dim(data) <- dim : invalid first argument

```
sigma <- matrix(c(1.0, 0,
                  0, 1.0), nrow = 2)
mu1 <- c(0.5,1.5)
mu2 <- c(1,2)
mu3 <- c(1.5,2.5)

sim=100
t2err=0
for (i in 1:sim){
  x1 <- data.frame(mvrnorm(n = 10, mu = mu1, Sigma = sigma),
                   subjects = c(rep('1', 10)))
  x2 <- data.frame(mvrnorm(n = 10, mu = mu2, Sigma = sigma),
                   subjects = c(rep('2', 10)))                
  x3 <- data.frame(mvrnorm(n = 10, mu = mu3, Sigma = sigma),
                   subjects = c(rep('3', 10)))
  x <- rbind(x1,x2,x3)
  ## p-value ##
  if (((summary(manova(as.matrix(cbind(x[,1:2])~x$subjects)),'Wilks'))$stats[1,6]) > 0.05) (t2err=t2err+1) 

}
cat("Power rate in percentage is",(1-(t2err/sim))*100,"%")
```

Does anyone know what went wrong? because when I do the same thing with only x1 instead of x=(x1,x2,x3), everything seems to be okay.

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't defined or created `data`. R is using the `data` function, which doesn't have a dimension (technically, it can't be dimensioned), hence error.

Comment: Do you want `dim (x)`?

Comment: And to follow @Edward's thought ... it's generally a bad idea to name a variable the same as an R function, especially because when it fails, it can give really obscure errors, such as `invalid 'type' (closure) of argument` (a common one when you expect to find a *variable* named `data` and instead try to do some math on a function) versus the simpler `object 'myvar' not found`.

Comment: Another one similar to `data` that many people use to name their data frames is `df`, which is a function that gives the density of the F distribution. My advice is to use Capitalized names for data frames (MVD or MVDdata) since _almost_ all R functions are totally lowercase.

Comment: And of course all my above comments were useless here! The problem was solved by PKumar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a problem with the `if` statement line, I have rectified the line with below one:

```
if (((summary(manova(as.matrix(x[,1:2])~ x$subjects),'Wilks'))$stats[1,6]) > 0.05) (t2err=t2err+1)
```

you don't need cbind over there plus as.matrix should be wrapped over `x[,1:2]` not on the entire formula, which might happened because of wrong order of parenthesis.

If you replace code with above line, it should work.

Comment: Yes. There was a problem with `as.matrix(cbind(x[,1:2])~x$subjects)`

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved the problem I was having.